# Linkning JButtons with array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, jbutton

I'm creating pair game in Java.
The idea is that i have 100 JButtons numered from 1 to 100, and all of them has assigned numbers from 1 to 50 (2x times). And when i click on any button it should show me the number assigned to that button. And the player have to find the second button with the same number. How can i assign that numbers to JButtons? Their names (1-100) should be visible so i cant just name buttons by the values and hide their names.

```
package pairgame; 

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class PairGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{ 
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file, help;
    JMenuItem fileExit, helpAbout; 
    JButton buttons[];

    ArrayList <Integer> numbers;

    void createMenuBar()
    {        
        file = new JMenu("File");
            fileExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            fileExit.addActionListener(this);
            fileExit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl Q"));
```

file.add(fileExit);
            file.setMnemonic('f');

```
    help = new JMenu("Help");
        helpAbout = new JMenuItem("About");
        helpAbout.addActionListener(this);
        helpAbout.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl H"));
        help.add(helpAbout);
        help.setMnemonic('h');

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(file);
        menuBar.add(help);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}

PairGame()
{
    setTitle("Pair Game");
    setSize(600,600);
    setLocation(400,100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

    createMenuBar();

                                        // CREATING GAME MAP

    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=1; i<=50; i++)
        numbers.add(i);
    for(int i=51; i<=100; i++)
        numbers.add(i-50);

    Collections.shuffle(numbers);      

    buttons = new JButton[100];
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        buttons[i] = new JButton(""+(i+1));
        buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        add(buttons[i]);
    }


    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    new PairGame();
} 


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if (source==fileExit)
        System.exit(0);

    if (source==helpAbout)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "blablabla", "About", 3);          

}
```

}

I just started writing so dont give me advice about construction etc because its pre-alpha version :)

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the values from the test by creating your own class that extends the JButton, for example:

```
public class PairButton extends JButton {

private final int myRealValue;

public PairButton(int myRealValue){
    this.myRealValue = myRealValue;
}

public int getMyRealValue() {
    return myRealValue;
}
```

}

Comment: Thats good idea but setName() and getName() solved my problem :)